# How should I change the event list as the month changes properly using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, web

THANKS IN ADVANCE

I am making a calendar that has a column for the months, colmn for events, and a column for event descriptions. How should I make it so that I am able to change the events when i clikc on different months?

"How should I change the event list as the month changes properly using jQuery?" 
this is my current code

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mitchell Bregman">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Community Page | Events</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){   

            $('#description').hide();
            $('.e1').hide();
            $('.e2').hide();
            $('.e3').hide();
            $('.e4').hide();

            $('.ev1').click(function(){
               $('#description').fadeIn();  
               $('.e1').show();
               $('.e2').hide();
                $('.e3').hide();
                $('.e4').hide();
            });

            $('.ev2').click(function(){
               $('#description').fadeIn();  
               $('.e2').show();
               $('.e1').hide();
                $('.e3').hide();
                $('.e4').hide();
            });

            $('.ev3').click(function(){
               $('#description').fadeIn();  
               $('.e3').show();
               $('.e2').hide();
                $('.e1').hide();
                $('.e4').hide();
            });

            $('.ev4').click(function(){
               $('#description').fadeIn();  
               $('.e4').show();
               $('.e2').hide();
                $('.e3').hide();
                $('.e1').hide();
            });



        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/kindajean.png');
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, span{
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    }
    #white_bar{
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1%;
        background-color: white;
        border-right: 1px solid #BABABA;
    }
    #months{
        width: 17%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 1%;
        position: absolute;
        background-image: linear-gradient(left , rgb(22,21,26) 0%, rgb(24,22,28) 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left , rgb(22,21,26) 0%, rgb(24,22,28) 100%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left , rgb(22,21,26) 0%, rgb(24,22,28) 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgb(22,21,26) 0%, rgb(24,22,28) 100%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left , rgb(22,21,26) 0%, rgb(24,22,28) 100%);

        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left top,
            right top,
            color-stop(0, rgb(22,21,26)),
            color-stop(1, rgb(24,22,28))
        );
        border-right: 1px solid #363636;
    }
    #months h1{
        font-size: 19px;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    #months li{
        list-style-type: none;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #BDBDBD;
        padding: 5px 0px 5px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
        -o-transition: all .2s ease;
        transition: all .2s ease;
    }
    #months li:hover{
        background-color: rgba(120, 120, 120, .12);
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
        -o-transition: all .2s ease;
        transition: all .2s ease;
    }
    #events{
        width: 28%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 18%;
        position: absolute;
        background-image: linear-gradient(left , rgb(174,170,189) 0%, rgb(190,187,199) 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left , rgb(174,170,189) 0%, rgb(190,187,199) 100%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left , rgb(174,170,189) 0%, rgb(190,187,199) 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgb(174,170,189) 0%, rgb(190,187,199) 100%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left , rgb(174,170,189) 0%, rgb(190,187,199) 100%);

        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left top,
            right top,
            color-stop(0, rgb(174,170,189)),
            color-stop(1, rgb(190,187,199))
        );
        border-right: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    }
    #events h1{
        font-size: 21px;
        color: black;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    #events li{
        list-style-type: none;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #333333;
        padding: 5px 0px 5px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
        -o-transition: all .2s ease;
        transition: all .2s ease;
    }
    #events li:hover{
        background-color: rgba(41, 127, 214, .5);
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
        -o-transition: all .2s ease;
        transition: all .2s ease;
    }
    #description{
        width: 500px;
        background-color: white;
        height: 90%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -45%;
        left: 46%;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: none;
    }
    #description p{
        padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="white_bar">
        </div>
        <div id="months">
            <h1>Months</h1>
            <li class="jan">January</li>

            <li class="feb">February</li>
            <li class="mar">March</li>
            <li class="apr">April</li>
            <li class="may">May</li>
            <li class="jun">June</li>
            <li class="jul">July</li>
            <li class="aug">August</li>
            <li class="sep">September</li>
            <li class="oct">October</li>
            <li class="nov">November</li>
            <li class="dec">December</li>
        </div>
        <div id="events">
            <h1>Events</h1>
            <li class="ev1">1/2/13 - General Meeting</li>
            <li class="ev2">Event 2</li>
            <li class="ev3">Event 3</li>
            <li class="ev4">Event 4</li>
        </div>
        <div id="description">
            <p class="e1">
            <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:400px;"><object type="text/html" data=".//Blank.html"" style="width:490px; height:1200px; margin:1%;"></object></div>
            </p>
            <p class="e2">event 2 desc</p>
            <p class="e3">event 3 desc</p>
            <p class="e4">event 4 desc</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"And make sure you post the code into a jsfiddle"_ isn't going to earn you any fans.

Comment: Probably not answer either.

Comment: sorry then. that was my friend// copy/paste

Comment: Protip: Use this instead of your current structure: $('#description, .e1, .e2, .e3, .e4').hide();

Comment: Here's a fiddle to start with: http://jsfiddle.net/k3MtK/2

Comment: so what exactly needs to be done to fix the problem? thanks!

Comment: Patience, young buck. Fiddle updated to fix HTML problem: http://jsfiddle.net/k3MtK/4

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#months li').click(function () {
    myClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.events').hide();
    $('.events.' + myClass).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3MtK/10/

Note that I stripped a bunch of stuff out to make it more clear what I'm doing, and I did add .events to your CSS. You can also use this example to make the rest of your code lighter.